# Where to find the .bashrc file on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Lion?

Tags: bash, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, osx-lion, .bash-profile

I want to install rvm on my Snow Leopard machine.

It says I need to add a line to my `.bashrc` file (I'm using bash) but where is my `.bashrc` file?

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer and accept it (You'll have to wait a day or two before SU allows you to do so) That way people with the same problem can look at the question can see that it has an answer.

Comment: His solution is no different from the top voted answer..

Comment: Just to make sure, this is not an issue of "Linux = .bashrc vs. Mac OS = .(bash_)profile" the  shell startup files work the same on Linux and Mac and the .bashrc file is the more aproperiate place for Session specific settings.  you use for example tmux or screen you might not have login sessions but still want your aliases. The reason Mac feels different is that most Linux distributions ship system profile scripts or skeleton profiles which already delegate (source) bashrc.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

So turns out that on Mac OS X Snow Leopard as well as Mac OS X Lion, the file that's loaded is called `.profile`, not `.bashrc`.

What you want to do is create a file in `~/.profile` and call it .profile (if it doesn't already exists).

Put whatever information you needed to load with each instance of bash there (Thanks, thepurplepixel).

***A couple of side notes:***

1. The period in front of the file marks it as invisible to Finder and
   the ls command by default. To list invisible files using the ls
   command from Terminal, use the `-a` as a parameter as such: `ls -a`
2. The `~` symbol stands for `/Users/YourUserName` where YourUserName
   is your username's shortname.

Edit: Chris Page notes (correctly) that whatever you place in a .profile file will apply to whatever shell you're using (i.e. zhs, bash, et cetera). If you want the contents to affect only the bash shell, place the contents in a `.bash_profile` file instead of a `.profile` file.

Comment: Your question was answered [correctly] on June 1 2010 -- one day after you asked it.  Over a year later, you come back and provide the exact same answer and accept your own answer...

Comment: Actually his answer does add more detail than the answer given on June 1 2010. He specifically addresses the issue on Mac OS X which I found helpful.

Comment: Note that if a `.bash_profile` already exists in your home directory, then `.profile` file will not be read!

Comment: I have a fresh Install of Mac Os El capitan. There is no *profile* file. Just create a .profile file and it works. I personally renamed my .bashrc to .profile.

Answer (score 84):

Regarding the problem with `.bashrc` above:

On most systems, `~/.bashrc` is only used when starting an *interactive **non-login** shell*. However, when you start up a new shell it is often an *interactive **login** shell*. Since this is a **login** shell, the `.bashrc` is ignored. To keep the environment consistent between non-login and login shells, you must source the `.bashrc` from your `.profile` or your `.bash_profile`.

See the Bash Reference Manual, section [6.2 Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

> **Invoked as an interactive login shell,
>   or with --login**
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option, it
>   first reads and executes commands from
>   the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists. After reading that file, it
>   looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands
>   from the first one that exists and is
>   readable.
>
> **Invoked as an interactive non-login shell**
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes
>   commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.
>
> So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile
>   contains the line
>
> ```
>    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
> ```
>
> after (or before) any login-specific initializations.

On my Mac (Running Leopard), there was no line to source `~/.bashrc`. I had to add this functionality on my own.

On some systems and other OSes, `.bashrc` is sourced from the global `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash_profile` , or is done using the template files from `/etc/skel`.

To be honest the distinction between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` is not well understood by the community. When many developers say "Add this to your .bashrc", what they really mean is "Add this to your .bash_profile". They want the functionality to be added to your *login* shell (which is `.bash_profile`), not to your *non-login* shell. In reality, it doesn't usually matter and placing configuration in `.bashrc` is acceptable.

Comment: This link gives a good overview of the types of shells and when startup files are loaded - http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile

Comment: What is meant by "sourced" here?

Comment: @elgrego , here's a good description: _When a file is sourced (by typing either source filename or . filename at the command line), the lines of code in the file are executed as if they were printed at the command line._ See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html

Answer (score 4):

You have to make your own `.bashrc`. You can simply use a text editor to make a file called `.bashrc` (no extension) with the contents you want and save it in your home directory (`/Users/YourUserName/`).

Comment: actually, that didn't work, but you did send me in the right direction by telling me to make my own file. The file that worked on a Snow Leopard configuration was .profile, not .bashrc (which is for some reason not loaded in this OS). I'll post detailed instructions in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Yuval: By default, a `.bashrc` will work, but *only if there is no `.profile`.* I guess `~/.profile` exists by default, though. Glad I could help! (And you should put your solution in an answer and accept it for future readers of this question).

Comment: I think your comment about *only if there is no .profile* is incorrect. .bashrc will work within a interactive non-login shell, or if it sourced from .profile (.bash_profile is probably a better place, since .profile is for the Bourne shell). .profile is used during an interactive non-login shell.

Comment: @Stefan That sounds correct, then. I'm not an expert :)

Comment: Nobody is ;). This stuff (.bashrc vs .profile vs. .bash_profile vs. .bash_login vs. interactive login shell vs interactive non-login shell vs non-interactive shell) is confusing, and it's broken and overridden by many Unixes and shell scripts.

Comment: Just tried this without a .profile, still doesn't get sourced in new terminal sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I find that in my OS 10.6.5 the bash settings are in "/etc/bashrc". I think this is the toplevel specifications for shell.

However, you need a root account to modify it. The local per-user specifications "~/.bashrc" should start with the following snippet, to read and load the system-level bash settings:

```
if [ -r /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc 
fi
```

I normally add aliases in the system level bashrc so that all users can access them as well. Unless they don't want to use your shortcuts and aliases.

Good luck!

Comment: /etc/profile (run by login shells) is a global bash startup script that applies to all users and provides default behaviors for login shells. It in turn runs /etc/bashrc, which contains customizations that apply to both login and non-login shells. Similarly, individual users should create a ~/.bash_profile file that runs ~/.bashrc, which is where most customizations should be, and ~/.bashrc should run /etc/bashrc to inherit default behaviors for non-login shells.

Comment: For individual users, it's best to add these customizations to your home directory at `~/.bashrc` , not `/etc/bashrc`. `/etc/bashrc` are the global settings for all users on your system, which probably isn't what you want. Also, Apple may come along and change `/etc/bashrc` periodically, which might blow away your customizations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .profile file to add anything that you would add to a linux .bashrc file.

For example

```
PATH=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/depot_tools/:~/bin:$PATH
alias t='/Users/<username>/.todo/todo.sh'
alias punch='python /Users/<username>/.todo/Punch.py'
alias clock='cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13'
alias sudotext="sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"
```

Comment: I recommend you use ~/.bash_profile (instead of ~/.profile) unless you're certain you want your customizations to take effect in other shells and that they're compatible.

Comment: Just to make sure, this is not an issue of "Linux = .bashrc vs. Mac OS = .(bash_)profile" the  shell startup files work the same on Linux and Mac and the .bashrc file is the more aproperiate place for Session specific settings.  you use for example tmux or screen you might not have login sessions but still want your aliases. The reason Mac feels different is that most Linux distributions ship system profile scripts or skeleton profiles which already delegate (source) bashrc.